# Getting a value from an Excel sheet column

Tags: c#, strings, .net, excel, interval

The code below gets value from a column in an Excel sheet.  The values I get are B1, B2, B3, B4...., B100, ...Bn. All I need to do is strip out the char 'B' and convert the numeric string to integer and count how many times a particular integer has repeated.

The snippet below shows the string stripping the char 'B'. However I feel it can be done in better way but I don't know how.

```
if (range.Text.ToString() == "BayID")
{
    range = null;
    range = readSheet.get_Range(cell, Missing.Value);
    while (range.Text.ToString() != "")
    {
        range = null;
        string A1 = String.Empty, Val = String.Empty;
        char[] value = null;
        range = readSheet.get_Range(cell, Missing.Value);
        A1 = range.Text.ToString();
        value = A1.ToCharArray();
        j++;
        cell = "D" + j;
        for (int i = 1; i < value.Length; i++)
        { 
            Val += value[i]; 
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused about the code, I think the end result of it is that it will do nothing. Also, have a look at the `Substring()` method.

Comment: Its a half baked cookie.. I am still working on it.. before pasting here I displayed a message box which showed the string and I understood that everything is working as expected..

Comment: @svick if you would paste that as an answer I would happily accept it.. the `Substring()` method worked greatly for me! :)

Comment: @vin please edit the title of your post to make it more Google-searchable & improve the site's visibility :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't be afraid of having more variables. I suspect that the value in `range` has a different contextual meaning when it is used in the first if clause vs the inside of the while loop. If this is the case, make two different variables with names that describe what the contextual meaning is for the specific variable. The type system will help you know the variable is a `Range`. A name like `price` or `id` (it all depends on what you are using it for) will make the code easier to read.

---

Building on what @Malachi said: You don't need to define your variables at the beginning and assign them a default value.

```
string A1 = String.Empty, Val = String.Empty;
char[] value = null;
range = readSheet.get_Range(cell, Missing.Value);
A1 = range.Text.ToString();
value = A1.ToCharArray();

//is the same as

range = readSheet.get_Range(cell, Missing.Value);
string A1 = range.Text.ToString();
char[] value = A1.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: Good point, I went with the assumption that the range Variable is being used for the same thing every time.

Answer (score 2):

you have this line

```
range = null;
```

and this line

```
range = readSheet.get_Range(cell, Missing.Value);
```

both inside and outside of your `While` Statement. this seems Odd to me?
from the code that you have given it looks like you can get rid of

```
range = null;
```

both times that it shows up.

your `range` variable is already created outside of this `if` statement, I don't think that you should need to set it to null everytime that you want to change it.

that paired with the `Substring()` Method that @svick mentioned would clean this up a bit I think.

Answer (score 0):

> **strip** out the char 'B' and **convert** the numberic string to integer and **count** how many times a particular integer has repeated

```
// the integer, it's count
Dictionary<int,int> integerCounter = new Dictionary<int,int>;
Regex stripB = new Regex(@"\d+");
int capturedNumber;

// may not be correct use of Worksheet properties
foreach (var cell in range) {
    if (Int32.TryParse(stripB.Match(cell.Text), out capturedNumber)) {

        if (!integerCounter.Contains(capturedNumber)) integerCounter.Add(capturedNumber, 1)
        else
            integerCounter[capturedNumber]++;
   }
}
```